# Browser back button going to Prev page after logout

Tags: angularjs, razor

I have logout button in my angularjs(1.8) application. On click of it calling the login page url. After logout, when i click the browser back button again it is going to my application page instead of login page.

```
<input type="button" id="btnLogout" value="Logout" name="btnLogout" style="background-color:crimson;color:white;font-weight:bold" ng-click="interfaceControllerVm.Logout()" />


angular.module("main")
    .controller("interfaceController", InterfaceController);

function InterfaceController($scope, $http) {
    var interfaceControllerVm = this;
   Initialize();
    function Logout() {
       
        interfaceControllerVm.loading = true;       
        var logouturl = "https://Loouturl.com/famlogout?";
      var loginurl = "https://Loginurl.com";
       window.location.replace(logoutUrl);

    }
}
```

Please suggest me what's wrong here

Thanks
Sam